# organise references alphabetically

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I have organised my bibliography as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Author (date)]{code} 

Author Name (date).

\textit{Title}. 

Publisher.

etc

\end{thebibliography}
```

Is there any way to organise the references alphabetically?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.se!

Comment: Well, if you do it this way you have to sort it manually. Why don't you use `biblatex` and an appropiate bibliographystyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

If you build the bibliography by hand, you are in charge of absolutely everything -- including the order of the appearance of the items.

You may want to look into creating bibliographies via tools such as BibTeX, which has been around for decades, and `biblatex`, which is (much!) more modern than BibTeX and offers more formatting and sorting options than BibTeX does. If you choose the BibTeX route, do also look into using a citation management package (e.g., `natbib`) for options for generating citation callouts.